# Animations PanResponder

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am stuck on my code, I would like to raise an Alert as soon as my user moves the square in the center of the screen.initiation position square is left,top.
someone can help me?

my file Animation.js

```html
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Dimensions, PanResponder } from 'react-native';

function pan_responde() {
    const [topPosition, setTopPosition] = useState(0);
    const [leftPosition, setLeftPosition] = useState(0);

    var {height, width } = Dimensions.get('window');
    
    const panResponder = PanResponder.create({
        onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
        onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {
            let touches = evt.nativeEvent.touches;

            if(touches.length = 1){
                setTopPosition(touches[0].pageY - height/2);
                setLeftPosition(touches[0].pageX - width/2);
            }
        }
    })
    return (
        <View style={styles.main_container}>
            <View
                {...panResponder.panHandlers}
                style={[styles.animation_view, {top: topPosition, left: leftPosition}]}
            >
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  main_container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  animation_view: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    width: 100,
    height: 100
  }
})


export default pan_responde;
```